# How to join two tables using group by and do the calculation?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to find the difference of amount between two tables using  linq group by.
There are two tables named TabA and TabB. Both tables have the same structure and the primary key. The primary keys are : Curr and Dept.

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

The Diff = TabA.Amt- TabB.Amt

I tried the below  partial code:

```
var q = from row in TabA.AsEnumerable().Concat(TabB.AsEnumerable())
        group row by new
        {
               currency = row.Field<String>("Curr"),
               dept = row.Field<String>("Dept")
        }into matches
        select new
        {
               currency = matches.Key.currency,
               dept = matches.Key.dept,
               // diff = Amount Difference
        };
```

Thanks for your solution:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff = matches.First().Field<decimal?>("Amt") - 
       matches.Skip(1).First().Field<decimal?>("Amt")
```

To handle for null elements, we need some *rule* to follow. However the code above will make the `diff` null when one of the 2 operands (or both) is null.

### UPDATE

To use the `0` as default value for `Amt`, you can use the method `GetValueOrDefault()` like this:

```
diff = matches.First().Field<decimal?>("Amt").GetValueOrDefault() - 
       matches.Skip(1).First().Field<decimal?>("Amt").GetValueOrDefault()
```

Comment: Complier(VS 2008) is giving an error. 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Amt'

Comment: Thanks King Kong for your help. I will be handling the null cases in my code

Comment: @Ullan you're welcome, the point is each group has 2 elements, the first is from the tableA, the second is from the tableB (in the order of `Concat`).

Comment: Thanks King King, I am trying to handle the null value as   dept = (matches.Key.dept ?? ""), But after reading 85 records, it throwing an error like "Sequence contains no elements". actually there around 100+ records exist in the table.

Comment: @Ullan it's not clear what you did. However what I meant about handling null values was **What's the default value of `diff` you want when one of `tabA.Amt` and `tabB.Amt` or both are `null`**?

Comment: @Ullan maybe you want to leave the `diff` as null in that case, if so we can cast to `decimal?` instead (also updated in my answer).

Comment: if tabA.Amt or tabB.amt  is null, I will take default value as 0. The error may not be related to null (Sequence contains no elements)

Comment: @Ullan see my update, note that, when you group as you did, you should be sure all the groups will have **2 elements** (this is because of the same structure of tabA and tabB). Both the `tabA` and `tabB` should have non-null keys (it should be that, otherwise your data is very abnormal and has something wrong).

Comment: I have implemented your code , still not handling the null values. If I comment out code //diff = .. , it completing the loop fine,